# Passport.JS stuck at redirecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redirect, passport.js

I'm having trouble with Passport.JS inside my Express app, more specifically the successful redirect for the registration/login. The username/password is being stored in DB without problems but the redirect in both cases is not working.

I'm using: Express, Body-Parser,, Mongoose, Passport, Passport-local and Passport-local-mongoose.

**Passport Config**

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "This is a test app",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser);
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser);
```

**Sign Up Route**

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render("register");
    }
    passport.authenticate("local"),(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    });
  });
});
```

**Login Route**

```
app.post("/login", 
passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/campgrounds",
  failureRedirect: "/login"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your passport config
and try to match variables names to yours in your application

```js
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
  usernameField : 'usernameFORM',
  passwordField : 'passwordFORM',
  passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, usernameCB, passwordCB, done) {

  // asynchronous
  process.nextTick(function() {

  //  Whether we're signing up or connecting an account, we'll need
  //  to know if the email address is in use.
  User.findOne({'username' :  usernameCB}, function(err, existingUser) {

      // if there are any errors, return the error
      if (err)
          return done(err);

      // check to see if there's already a user with that email
      if (existingUser)
          return done(null, false);

      //  If we're logged in, we're connecting a new account.
      if(req.user) {
        console.log(req.user);
          var user              = req.user;
          User.username    = usernameCB;
          User.password = user.generateHash(passwordCB);
          User.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                  throw err;
              return done(null, user);
          });
      }
      //  We're not logged in, so we're creating a brand new user.
      else {
          // create the user
          var User            = new User();

          User.username    = usernameCB;
          User.password =   User.generateHash(passwordCB);

          User.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                  throw err;
              return done(null, user);
          });
      }});
  });
}));
```

and in your routes

```js
    app.post('/signup',passport.authenticate('local-signup',{
      successRedirect:'/campgrounds',
      failureRedirect:'/login'
    }))
```